# where is processing.py's modules that are imported?

Tags: processing

I was reading one of the examples in `processing.py`,  `Arctangent`. It has an import statement:

```
from eye import Eye
```

I cannot figure out where this 'eye' library that I'm importing from is located.   I don't see it in the [processing.py reference](https://py.processing.org/reference/).   I searched the filesystem under the `processing-3.5.4/ subdirectory` and cannot find any module named `eye` either.

The program works.  But I wonder where these modules are, and where can I find a reference for them. I'm wondering now what else is available that I cannot see.

Comment: From using the `.__file__` attribute of modules, mine installed in my Documents folder under `Processing\modes\PythonMode\mode\jython.jar\Lib\threading.py`. I used the `threading` module but I imagine others would follow a similar hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to notice that the example had a second tab with the code to be imported. These aren't standard library modules.

[image]